# Httphandler and Httpmodule in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

As i know that asp.net fulfill all the requirements for any web application but what are the ground rules for creating custom httphandler and httpmodule in asp.net.

Edit:For example I want to fetch image from database then what i should i use httphandler or normally read image from database.If httphandler then why?

Comment: "Group Rules" in what respect?  I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Please elaborate more on your question, it's a little broad...

Comment: @Chris & Brian:I want to fetch image from database and my architect suggest me to use httphandler so that i asked this question what are the ground rules for deciding when to use custom handler or module in asp.net

Comment: It's a matter of using the right tool for the right job. It would be good for you to learn more about the HttpHandler and HttpModule objects to understand what they do and why they were created. Once you know what exactly the tools do, you will be able to choose the right one. For what it's worth, it sounds to me like your architect has a good understanding of them. I agree with his recommendation.

Comment: @Joel:You are right.So that I have posted to this forum to increase my understanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTPHandlers to handle the request. But HTTPModules are to access the life-cycle events on the request. You can have only one HTTPHandler but can plug in more than one HTTPModules to examine and handle the requests.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, now that we know you want to pull an image from a database.

Yes, using a Generic Handler (.ashx) is the best way to do this.

It's as simply as saying Add | New Item and picking Generic Handler from the list.

Generic handlers do not have the full page life cycle which makes them both faster and easier to deal with.  You just need to provide some code in the ProcessRequest method to pull the image out of the database and response.binarywrite it to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

As a thumb rule `HttpHandlers` are when you need to serve something to the browser, a page, image or some concrete resource. While `HttpModules` are for responding to events in the pipeline happening on the server. Ie handling errors, rewriting the url, logging stuff, checking for login-cookie, filtering the input or output stream etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

First off, keep in mind that an ASP.NET page is an HTTP Handler, just one that's more feature-rich. (The `System.Web.UI.Page` class implements `IHttpHandler`.)

As Chris Lively noted, a generic HTTP Handler - that is a class you create that implements `IHttpHandler` - is going to be simpler and more efficient than using a standard ASP.NET page because it doesn't go through the entire page lifecycle, allows you to focus on just crafting the output in the `ProcessRequest` method, and so on.

But if the task at hand is specifically to display an image from a database, rather than writing your own HTTP Handler consider using the [GeneratedImage control](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/16449) from Microsoft.

In a nutshell, the GeneratedImage control is an HTTP Handler base class created by Microsoft that is designed to display database images. It's easy to use, supports caching and a host of other features. Why reinvent the wheel?

For more information on using this, see: [Dynamically Generating and Caching Images in ASP.NET with the GeneratedImage Control](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111734/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/042209-1.aspx). Here's the article's synopsis:

> The GeneratedImage control is a combination of an ASP.NET Web Control and a set of classes that facilitate programmatically creating, serving, caching, and transforming images. If you store images in the database that need to be served from a web page, if you need to create images on the fly, or if you need to resize, add watermarks, or perform some other image transform, then the GeneratedImage control can help.

Happy Programming!

Answer (score 0):

- **HTTP Module:** Is called every time before and after the request.
- **HTTP Handler:** Is the Process to handling the Request (Specially `.aspx` page)